# Why also using magnetometers in IMUs?

Tags: sensor, imu, magnetometer, compass

Why do we also use magnetometers when building IMUs, that is why don't we simply and only use gyroscopes and accelerometers?

I also would like to know how does a magnetometer work as a 3-axis device?

Furthermore, how are the three sensors working together?

Comment: acceleromenters, gyros and magnetometers have drifts, margins and errors in slightly different ways, so you use data from one sensor to correct or complete another.. (accelerometer for short term and magnetometer for long term for example)

Comment: Source of error for magnetometer can be any large iron-bearing object or any magnetic field caused by something other than Earth. However, they are relatively drift free, even in the presence of such errors. The big problem with angular rate sensors (gyros) is drift. The magnetometer can just about cancel out the drift error in an angular rate sensor. Of course, if you are in a moving vehicle, and the vehicle itself has a strong magnetic field, and the magnetometer is "captured" by that field, then it will create big problems for angular rate sensor drift cancellation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accelerometers can itself measure the inclination, they have a slow response.     Gyros measure angle rate change, fast response, but the problems for gyros is the zero drift and it has to be compensated for any usable application.

While at steady state, a filter is used such that accelerometers track and eliminate the gyro drift in the vertical plane, where the gravity vector is used for inclination (roll, pitch), but in horizontal plane heading/yaw there is not such possibility, therefore magnetometer can be used. A magnetometer is mainly used for speed detection and with fusion algorithm it can eliminate the gyro offset.

The only such known algorithm (in my knowledge) is Sebastian Madgwick's fusion algorithm. Others (Kalman filter, direct cosine matrix DCM) use accelerometer and gyros, only.

Comment: There's nothing slow about accelerometers.  If speed is an issue, it is algorithmic and has little to do with the sensor.

Comment: oh okay thanks for this information,but Is there is a pdf file or something about how it works?

Comment: http://www.x-io.co.uk/res/doc/madgwick_internal_report.pdf  You can find open source of this algorithm in various platforms, Arduino, etc..just search Madgwick IMU, also youtube presentations..  http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa518a/slaa518a.pdf Direction cosine matrix

Answer (score 0):

There is also Mahony's Algorithm, besides many versions of Kalman Filters can use magnetometers readings to correct gyro bias and long therm drift.

The Mag readings are used in a similar manner to those from Accelerometers

Comment: This is an old question, so if you're going to add an answer years after it was asked it would be useful if you could provide a little more detail.

Comment: Sorry, here you go with some code examples:
An example of EKF [link](https://la.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63250-gyrolib-ahrs-library)
I would say that it looks like a Multiplicative Extended Kalman Filter - or just MEKF. Actually, there are a number of mathematical formulations for Kalman Filters aiming to perform orientation estimation.
Madgwick wrote down his and Mahony's Algorithms and made available here [link](http://x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/).